# Image Icon won't appear

Tags: java, jframe, imageicon

I am trying to add an Image Icon to my game so a logo appears when it is in the task bar. I get no errors when I run my code but the image won't appear.

```
public class Game implements Runnable {
    public static Game game = null;
    Thread GameThread = new Thread(this);
    GamePanel panel = new GamePanel(this);
    GameFrame frame = new GameFrame(panel);

    ImageIcon logo = new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("res/duckIcon.png")); //for image icon
public Game() {
        changeState(sceneNum);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setIconImage(logo.getImage());
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

This is the GameFrame class:

```
public class GameFrame extends JFrame {

    GameFrame(GamePanel panel) {
        this.setSize(Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH, Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setTitle("Duck World");
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

I've tried implementing the IconImage in the GameFrame class to no avail. If anyone would like to look at the file structure, here is github link: https://github.com/stefancohn/DuckWorld

Comment: the directory must be on your classpath.

Comment: This is a duplicate. Can't at the moment find the original

Comment: @camickr What do you mean by this? Sorry I'm still learning.

Comment: The classpath contains the list of directories to search for the given file and or Java classes. This can be configured in your IDE or it can be set up as an environment variable if executing from the command line. Do a search for "Java classpath" for more information.